# Facebook unable to post video on test user page with test user access token

Tags: facebook, testing, facebook-test-users

I use the Facebook graph api to post a video:

```
https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/{page_id}/videos?title=video&access_token={
page_access_token}&file_url={file_path
}
```

When I login as app developer, using developer page_id and page_access_token, the call is good. It returns me the video id.

When I login as test user (not tester account in the App role), using test user page_id and page_access_token, I got:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) No permission to publish the video","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

I use Facebook token debug. Both tokens have the same scope
user_videos, manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions, public_profile.

Since both access tokens carry the same scope, why has the test user call return no permission to publish video even though the token has publish_actions, publish_page permission? But the admins/developers are able to post video?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The OAuthException makes me believe there's a problem with your access token, did you create it correctly? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

(From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#errors)

OAuthException: Login status or access token has expired, been revoked, or is otherwise invalid

Comment: well i reset the access token but still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I found your app's test users can not administer any pages. So your application's test user will not be able to post on any page.

It is a good idea to record a video with a real user publishing a video to a Facebook page with your application for the review.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the sdk to [V2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/) and now video upload is working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

For "**publish_actions**" you need to submit a request to facebook.

Here's a tutorial http://help.tanaza.com/customer/portal/articles/1655303-how-to-get-publish_actions-facebook-permission

I'm using FacebookSDK 3.23.2 for iOS and I have the same problem. I can upload videos with my dev account, but the tester can't. The tester's token is "publish_actions"..-less.

Comment: I submit request to facebook and the response was: `Your app uses a social plugin or share dialog to share content to Facebook. These don't need write permissions and don't need to be submitted for review. Our sharing docs have more information, and you can find the most up-to-date plugin versions here.` but my error still happens